# One To Many Relationship Supporting Reads but not INSERTS

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I am using spring boot (verson 2.1.1) to create an application that needs to one-to-many & many-to-one relationship between two model classes with below requirements

The model classes are

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORGANIZATIONS")
public class Organization{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Private long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    Private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENTS")
Public class Department{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   Private long id;

   @Column(unique=true)
   Private String name;


//…

}
```

Requirements

1. Both organizations and departments should be created by separate respective rest api's.

   - Through the POST /organizations api we should be able to create an organization without creating departments in the same api call. In fact the api should fail I tried to pass the json element for department as part of the POST /organizations call.
   - When calling POST /departments I should be able to pass the organization id to associate the newly created department with the organization.
2. The GET /organizations api call should return the Collection as part of the organization object

The questions are

1. How do I associate the two model objects ? Do I add @OneToMany in Organization? What attributes do I pass to @OneToMany? Do I need a similar @ManyToOne on the other side - department?
2. Do I need any special considerations on the REST controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `@ManyToOne` for persisting in `Department` only but you most likely will need `@OneToMany` in `Organization` for the GET request.

Just make sure, when saving the Department, that you need to:

- Fetch from db the organization
- Set the fetched organization on the department object
- Add the department to the Organization.departments list
- Persist the department

For the error handling return a `BAD_REQUEST` response:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Comment: How do I error out the POST /organizations when a department object is passed with it?

Comment: So I would have to explicitly check in the POST /organizations implementation if a department object is passed? If so I error out. Is there anything out of the box?

Comment: You could put that logic in a filter to have the endpoint more clean

Comment: while this worked for inserts and read, I forgot to mention about deletes. I want to delete the departments when I delete the organization. While I tried different combinations of cascades but it either doesn't work or breaks the previous insert/read logic. Could you guide me?